# template array class is not working properly

Tags: c++, templates

Template class :

```
#ifndef ARRAYC_H
#define ARRAYC_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class Array
{
private:
    T* m_ptr;
    int m_size;
public:
    Array();
    Array(int size);

    ~Array();

    int size() const;

    bool is_Empty() const;

    T& operator[](int index);
};

#endif
```

and class declaration Header..

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
#include "ArrayC.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int size) {
    if(size!=0) {
        T* m_ptr = new T[size]{};
        m_size = size;
    }
}
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array() {
    cout <<"Deleted" << endl;
    delete [] m_ptr;
}

template <class T>
int Array<T>::size() const {
    return m_size;
}

template <class T>
bool Array<T>::is_Empty() const {
    return (m_size==0);
}

template <class T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](int index) {
    if(index< m_size) {
        return m_ptr[index];
    }
    else {
        cout <<"Index Specifed is out of Range" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}

#endif
```

program

```
#include "Array.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Array<int> A(2); 
    A[0] = 1;
    A[1] = 2;
    cout << A[0] << endl;
    cout << A[1] << endl;
}
```

it compiles and also outputs value but
then it stops and then makefile shows error.

```
g++ -g -std=c++17 -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++17 -o Execute Main.o
Execute
1
2
Deleted
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'run' failed
mingw32-make: *** [run] Error -1073741819
```

after deleted is printed it stops for some time and then shows error.
run target only has one recipe that is to execute the program Execute.exe.
Really sorry for this type of description 
but its doesnt show any type of error.

```
CCX_FLAGS = g++ -g -std=c++17
CCX_OF = -o
CCX_CF = -c

.PHONY : all preExwork Obclean Exclean
all : preExwork run Obclean

preExwork : 
    $(CCX_FLAGS) $(CCX_CF) $(CCX_OF) Main.o Main.cpp
    $(CCX_FLAGS) $(CCX_OF) Execute Main.o 

run :
    Execute

Obclean : 
    del /f Main.o

Exclean :
    del /f Execute.exe
```

Comment: You have not shown the information that is critical to addressing your problem - the contents of the Makefile.

Comment: Is makefile really that important..? Dont take me wrong it only shows error in run target which has the recipe to run execute...

Comment: The output you provided was from a make process (e.g. from typing "make run" or "make all" or similar).   The output indicated that compiling, linking, and running your program all occurred, but then the make program itself reported an error.   Since the makefile is what controls make, the makefile is relevant to your problem.

Comment: ok.. So whats the error?? I mean solution